# restfullapi event calling in Yii

Tags: api, rest, yii

I am working on Rest Api on YII. I integrated RESTFULL extention. In this some one used this below code. What is SINGLE in below onRest Event. Can anybody explain plz.

```
$this->onRest('req.get.single.render', function ($id, $user_id) {

                $data="hi"; 
        $this->emitRest('req.render.json', [
            [
                'type' => 'raw',
                'data' => $data
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's might be called when a GET request for a single resource is to be rendered. But, I never saw **SINGLE** in ***Yii RESTFULL extension's** event. You can reference in **[this](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/restfullyii/)** or **[this](https://github.com/evan108108/RESTFullYii)**